# Custom Shoutcast Server - Audio is Distorted After Client Buffers

Tags: audio, stream, buffer, shoutcast, icecast

So, I'm in the process of writing my own implementation of the Shoutcast protocol.  It is going rather nicely.  I have it completely written, and when my internet is good, and I don't have to pause to buffer, the stream works perfectly.  Sometimes it even glitches at random.  Despite this issue, it changes songs and everything.  But once I start to buffer, everything goes downhill.  The audio is distorted until I stop and restart the connection on the client end.  I think that the cause for this is the icy-metaint header that I sent is off (on the client end), even though it is sent correctly from the server.  How do applications like Shoutcast and Icecast compensate for this?  I assume it has something to do with MTU, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.  The chunks of music that are sent are the exact same size every time.  The metadata should also be compliant with the parsers in most clients.  Here is the project on GitHub:  https://github.com/ClayFreeman/Radio-PHP

Comment: A few things: 1. It's hard to give an answer to a complex question like this without more info. 2. Posting complete code is not going to help -- probably noone will wade through it, especially if this isn't going to help other people. 3. Beyond starting and stopping the stream, what debugging have you done? eg. What happens when the client doesn't send the Icy-Metadata header?

Comment: 4. I can tell you it has nothing to do with the MTU, which is at the physical connection layer, which is something you shouldn't be thinking about since since shoutcast runs on TCP. You may be thinking of packet size, but AFAIK, packet size is irrelevant for shoutcast.

Comment: If you don't send the icy-metadata header, the stream will act in the same manner that it does right after the stream buffers.  I'll try to elaborate more on why I think it screws up; I think it is due to the player buffering at random in the middle of a chunk, and there is an offset from the true icy-metadata placement.  I don't see how this could be the problem, or any way that I could fix it.  Maybe packet loss is the cause?  But then again, why doesn't it do this on actual shoutcast streams?

Comment: You don't have a packet loss issue.  This is TCP.  Your packets will arrive in the same order in which they are sent.  I'm not going to dig through all of your code, but make sure you aren't using chunked encoding.  Are you actually inserting metadata at the correct intervals?

Comment: The only thing that I can determine that *could* be causing this issue is the metadata format is incorrect, causing the client to think there is more or less of the metadata than there really is, so it is either treating some audio as metadata, or some metadata as audio.  The first byte of the metadata must be equal to 1/16th of the actual length of metadata, rounded up.  So basically, $m = chr(ceil(strlen($payload) / 16)).$payload.str_repeat(chr(0), (ceil(strlen($payload) / 16) * 16) - strlen($payload));  Then, just send the chunk with the above number with the metadata: return $chunk.$m;

Comment: Oh, and just for the record, this application has no HTTPd frontend.  The content of the stream is purely application controlled.